# Hide get parameters from access logs on nginx

Tags: nginx, log-files

I would like to enable access log in order to see statistics about our service, the problem I'm having is that the $request on the access logs format, saves all the GET parameters (which makes sense because its part of the request)

but I would like to hide this information, so instead of seeing this on the logs:

```
98.207.174.147 - - [26/Apr/2014:23:59:09 +0000] "GET /v1/api.json?parameter1=value1&paramter2=value2" HTTP/1.1" 200 13449 "-" "httperf/0.9.0"
```

I would like to see

```
98.207.174.147 - - [26/Apr/2014:23:59:09 +0000] "GET /v1/api.json" HTTP/1.1" 200 13449 "-" "httperf/0.9.0"
```

Comment: Use POST requests.

Comment: Its not just for the benchmarking, our service should allow users to run search though GET requests, unfortunately that's not an option for me :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `log_format` directive of `ngx_http_log_module` .

for example, this format would only show the uri without any query string:

```
http {
       log_format combined_no_query '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
           '"$uri" $status $body_bytes_sent '
           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
       //other configs ...
     }

 server {
       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined_no_query
       //... 
      }
```

Notice the `$uri` variable which is used to log only the uri without any query string.

doc for `log_format` directive : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

for more variables:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was the solution I was looking for :)

Comment: Please note you are missing the request method (GET/POST etc.), so be sure to to include $request_method before $uri: `'"$request_method $uri" $status $body_bytes_sent '`